# using Xcode designer for xamarin storyboard

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios

I try to use xcode storyboard designer & xamarin ios designer on the same storyboard and I am experiancing some issues/inconsitencies . Does any one has experience to make it work or could recommend me to not mix both designer ?

Answer (score 0):

You **should** be able to switch between Xcode's Interface Builder and the iOS Designer at will, without issue so it sounds like you are running into an edge case.

Would you mind filling a bug report at [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com) against the iOS Designer explaining the issue, and if possible attach the Storyboard in issue?